# save_screenshot() vs get_screenshot_as_file() in Selenium in Python

Tags: python, django, selenium-webdriver, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

I took 2 screenshots of Django Admin with `save_screenshot()` and `get_screenshot_as_file()` as shown below. *I use [Django](https://github.com/django/django), [pytest-django](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django) and [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium):

`save_screenshot()`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

def test_1(live_server):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
    driver.save_screenshot("admin.png") # Here
```

`get_screenshot_as_file()`:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

def test_1(live_server):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(("%s%s" % (live_server.url, "/admin/")))
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("admin.png") # Here
```

Then, I got the same screenshots as shown below:

`admin.png`:

[image]

So, what is the difference between `save_screenshot()` and `get_screenshot_as_file()` in Selenium in Python?

Answer (score 1):

`save_screenshot()` and `get_screenshot_as_file()` are duplicates.

The first one just calls the second one, as seen here:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/3804/files